# obtaining android layout parameter 'MATCH_PARENT' actual value

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an xml layout which places an image at the top of the screen, and some text at the bottom. In between the two I have a Gallery widget which I populate with images all of the same size

The reasoning for this, is that I can call
`.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)` and the gallery images will fit the space inbetween the image and text perfectly.

The problem I am having is that I don't want the images to get too large. For small resolutions, filling the parent is good. When the resolutions increase, the images become too large and I need a 'cap' of around 200-300 dp.

Is there a way to obtain  the integer value of the LayoutParam.MATCH_PARENT? then I can perform a comparison and limit the size.

edit - code

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/chooseanimage" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="50dp"
                         ads:adUnitId="--"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,00"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         />


                    <Gallery
                        android:id="@+id/gallery"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
                        />

        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

and java

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if( !(convertView instanceof ImageView)){
        convertView = new ImageView(this.myContext);
       convertView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
        ((ImageView) convertView).setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }
    ((ImageView) convertView).setImageResource(this.myImageIds[position]);
     return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the match_parent attribute is intended for when the surface is created. Before then, the integer value of this attribute is -1 and is meaningless. As far as I know there is no way of obtaining what value it will take once the surface has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) parameter in the ImageView?

Comment: I suppose CENTER_INSIDE would work to some degree. However, the image would still be inside a rather necessarily large gallery frame? I am trying to limit the size of the gallery rather than the images inside it

Comment: Done. I am starting to wonder if a solution would be just to have different xml files for the small,normal,large resolutions and just specify a dp value for the size of the gallery.

Comment: I copied your code into my project and looks ok.. can you post an screenshot of your problem?